# Faster way to refresh a table in Oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have a procedure in Oracle 10g that copies data from a staging table to a main table.

```
-- move data to final table
DELETE FROM my_table;
INSERT INTO my_table
    SELECT * FROM my_table_s;
COMMIT;
```

This table has ~3M records.  The delete statement is very slow. I can speed it up with a TRUNCATE, but that creates a small window of time where the data is unavailable.

Is there a better way to do this type of move that both maintains the data availability to whomever may be querying at any given time and would not invalidate any packages using these table objects?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Materialized Views:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10706/repmview.htm

You can create a MView and then refresh it manually. You can speed up the refreshing mechanism by using the FAST REFRESH mechanism (using Materialized View Logs).

Answer (score -1):

using materialized view will not push back the changes have been made to the view whatever its type writable or read only or others so its better to do bulk select operation on desired table and commit operation will done that.